# Prometehus target Invalid Urls syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, prometheus

Im trying to add a target I configured in an AWS EC2 container

```
  GNU nano 2.5.3                                                      File: prometheus.yml                                                                                                                  

# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

  # Attach these labels to any time series or alerts when communicating with
  # external systems (federation, remote storage, Alertmanager).
  external_labels:
      monitor: 'codelab-monitor'

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first.rules"
  # - "second.rules"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'sit'

    # Override the global default and scrape targets from this job every 5 seconds.
    scrape_interval: 5s

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8000','localhost:9100','localhost:9125', 'localhost:9102', 'localhost:8125', 'http://test-elasticloa-y0avx674hv7dr7x-1495584279.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/prometheus']
```

However Im getting an error message arguing that my URL is not valid. How can I get the correct syntax for my URL?

```
ERRO[0000] Error loading config: couldn't load configuration (-config.file=prometheus.yml): "http://test-elasticloa-y0avx674hv7dr7x-1495584279.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/prometheus" is not a valid hostname  source=main.go:149
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the [code](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/config/config.go#L502), it appears you can't have forward slashes in there - try removing that.

Answer (score 1):

What you want here is to set the metrics_path to `/prometheus` for this target, though it'd be better if it served on the standard `/metrics` in the first place.

To give a bit of a history, it used to be the case that all addresses were full URLs. About two years ago this was changed so that addresses are just host:port to keep things cleaner. This error comes from aiding that transition.